# grub password protection necessary or overkill in an encrypted system?

Tags: security, grub, encryption

I run debian with full encryption and wonder why I would also need a password protection for the bootloader...

Comment: What threat models are you interested in addressing?

Comment: If someine gets hold of my laptop, I want to make sure he cannot access data on my HDD. Encryption should be enough I assume

Answer (score 1):

If the attacker has had full physical access to your device, your password protection is void and null because the attacker could:

- plant a hardware backdoor
- change your initrd in ways which allow to compromise your boot process and the installed OS

The GRUB password might protect from inexperienced hackers but not from sophisticated ones. I personally use full disk encryption and I didn't set the GRUB password.

Comment: thank you, I was thinking the same

Comment: I agree, and have the same sort of setup ;-). For more on this, look up evil maid attacks.